# Page reloads on hide/show button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using jQuery to show/hide a `div` by clicking on the show/hide buttons. However, my code doesn't work because every time it returns to the way it was before when I click on my buttons. I'm almost sure that this is due to a page reload, because every time I click on a button it reloads the page.
Does anybody know what could be the reason behind this?

Here is the important chunk of code:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="./something.php">
  ...
  <button id="hidemultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').hide(); $(this).hide(); $('#showmultmachines').show();">
    Hide section below ...
  </button>
  <button id="showmultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').show(); $(this).hide(); $('#hidemultmachines').show();">
    ... Create multiple entries
  </button>
  <div id="multmachines">
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="total" value="{ $smarty.section.i.total }">
      <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is my jQuery code in the header:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hidemultmachines').hide();
    $('#multmachines').hide();
}
```

When I put the buttons outside the form it works. Why?

Comment: This is really bad practice to use onclick like this.
in your 'ready' section add this: $('#hidemultmachines').click(function() { ... your click code here... } );

Comment: Because a button in the form creates a submit by default, reloading the page. Place this in a `click` event and use `e.preventDefault()`. Or place your buttons outside of your form. Or change the `type`.

Comment: Folks have already helped you -- inasmuch this is bad practice to use onClick like this -- but you *can* also just add    `;return false;` at the end of your string of javascript commands in the onclick -- and it will stop submitting.   That essentially is "stop bubbling this event".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because your `button` elements have no `type` specified, and by default `button` elements have their `type` set to "submit". When you click one of the buttons, they attempt to submit your form. Simply specifying a `type` of "button" will fix this:

```html
<button type="button" class="close" id="hidemultmachines" onclick="..."></button>
```

Comment: real hero is here !

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here:

1) It would be best to separate the HTML from the jQuery. 
2) The default behavior for a button is to submit a form, which means it will refresh the page if there is no form action. This can be fixed with preventDefault()

To sum this up in code:

HTML

```
<button class="close" id="hidemultmachines" >Hide section below <img alt="Close" width="35" height="35" src="../images/close.png"> </button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#hidemultmachines").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#multmachines').hide();    
  $(this).hide();
  $('#showmultmachines').show();
});
});
```